# Hough transform and openCV

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I am having doubt in understanding hough transform. Does in hough transform the angel theta means the lines in which lines needs to be detected like if I want to detect lines in 30 or 50 or 60 or 70 or 80, then should I just change the value of theta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html). The angle theta is drawn in the first figure. It actually is a parameter of the expression of the line in the polar coordinate system.

Comment: then how can I use hough transform to detect lines in different directions?

Comment: Read the tutorial until the end.